# How to get the currently logged in CustomUser object

Tags: spring-security

So i am trying to figure out if there is a simpler and more straightforward way of obtaining a CustomUser object for the currently logged in user.

I have a custom UserServiceImplementation and use a Custom User object.

Reading around i noticed the use of @AuthenticationPrincipal but i cannot seem to get any examples of it working. Furthermore it depends on @EnableWebMVCSecurity which is depreciated for the current version of spring security that i am using (4.x.x).

Am i looking at the right functionality to be able to achieve my goal or should i be looking at something completely different?

Example of my current code where i am forced to get current user object for the logged in user to be able to achieve further processing.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/map", method = method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processMap(@Valid MapProc mapObject) {
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

User user = userInterface.findByLogin(((UserDetails) principal).getUsername());

// rest of code

return "map/processed";
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you can't store this object inside the session?

Comment: From my understanding the system already returns a user object but an internal version. I read there is a way it can do for custom user object which makes life simpler in some aspects of coding, persisting it through session doesn't seem reasonable if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
 String userName= auth.getName();
```

Comment: I am after the object not just username, that does the same thing as SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal().getUsername()

Answer (score 0):

In the Session is always the UserDetails object from the UserDetailsService persistent. If you have your own Implementation witch returns your own User Object you get it by:

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
if (principal instanceof User) {
   //Your Code here
}
```